# How to get Paste menu to show in textarea on Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, copy-paste

When typing in a textarea on Chrome for Android (such as when asking this question), I can't figure out how to get the Paste menu to show. If I long press, Chrome wants to highlight. Of I double trap, the blue cursor just shows.

Occasionally, the Paste menu does show after repeated taps and holds, but I have found no reproducible actions that get it to show.

This might be a system-wide problem, but Chrome seems to be where I notice it. I'll reply back if I find the issue in other applications.

I'm on Chrome v39 on Android 4.4.4 (Moto Turbo).

Comment: If you have copied a text before, the "Paste" pop-up menu should appear when you long-press inside a text box. That's a universal action on Android. [The manual also says so](http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-117718/).

Comment: I'll have to film a video of not getting that behavior. Instead, long press highlights the current word, or if at end of a line, highlights the last word (or the line break to the next line). Note: long press works in Chrome address bar, but not textareas

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what I was missing. I'll post as answer

Answer (score 1):

As my question indicated, long pressing in a textarea (i.e. the multi line html input box) will highlight the word (or the nearest word/whitespace), and double tapping does what a single tap does: shows the blue cursor button.

The trick I was missing is that once the blue cursor button is showing, I tap this button to get the Paste menu to show. Once the Paste menu is showing, clicking around will move the cursor and the Paste menu.